# Which applications parallel transport have?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am looking for some applications of parallel transport. I have seen that, for example, one can find connection by using parallel transport.

Which other application the parallel transport might have that make it interesting to study or in other words

> Why we do parallel transport of a vector along a curve?

Comment: Probably not exactly what you're asking but I think it's pretty cool that you can view a [Focault pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum) as an instance of parallel transport.